# % operator in for loop (not modulo operator!)

Tags: c++-cli

I found some code written by a coworker by accident that compiles but we both do not know what it really means:

What does the `%` sign in following code do?

```
for (auto% layer : layers) { /* ...*/ }
```

This actually is a typo and was meant to be following:

```
for (auto &layer : layers) { /* ...*/ }
```

Comment: Minimal complete example, please. GCC: `error: expected unqualified-id before '%' token`.

Comment: It's a reference access in a [ranged for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: maybe you get this error because this happens in a c# wrapper class - we have CLR enabled in the project

Comment: Might be worth checking it on compiler explorer. Could be a bug, weird extension, or the code itself might be unintentionally compiled out?

Comment: yes, its a cli extension: https://godbolt.org/z/1Kor3M1x8

Comment: @infinitezero Not like any I've ever seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` is the c++-cli [Tracking Reference Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I could not find anything googling with a single character not knowing what else I should look for

Comment: @prom85 My path was to google "c++ cli grammar" which got me to [C++/CLI Cheat Sheet](https://manski.net/2011/04/cpp-cli-cheat-sheet/), searching there for `%` got the name of the operator then it was trivial to search MSDN for the documentation (via another google for "c++ cli handle reference")

Comment: thanks. actually I just knew it was a cli error after you posted the godbolt code - in my codebase it compiles error free and I did not think of trying to put the code inside a project without clr to get an error with some information